# Split a column into two columns based on number in the int

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code currently:

```
create table client (
  client_id int,
  birth_number int,
  district_id int
  Primary Key (district_id)
);

truncate client;

load data local infile 'C:\\Users\\james\\Desktop\\Wecloud_Data_Bootcamp\\bank_loan\\client.asc'
into table client
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines
(client_id, @birth_number, district_id)
SET birth_number = REPLACE(@birth_number, '"','');

-- Check the table
select * from client;
```

this is the current table

[image]

What I need to do is split the birth_number column into two columns, which are birthday date and gender respectively. The instructions are below, probably integer manipulation is needed, how do I do so?

[instruction of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JGRc.png)

[details of the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH1Bp.png)

Comment: It has gender inside, the birday and gender are both in the birth_numbers. the number is in the form YYMMDD for men and YYMM+50DD for women, YYMMDD is the birth date

Comment: @JamesZhao you need to describe what you have done so far to get to the answer for this question, otherwise it will be us solving it instead of you and that's not the point of a homework!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
     DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(birth_number, 1, 2), 
          IF(SUBSTR(birth_number, 3, 2) > 50, 
          SUBSTR(birth_number, 3, 2) - 50, SUBSTR(birth_number, 3, 2)), 
          SUBSTR(birth_number, 5, 2)),
         '%Y-%M-%d'
     ) AS `date`, 
     IF(SUBSTR(birth_number, 3, 2) > 50, 'Female', 'Male') AS Gender
FROM `client`
```

Change the format of the date as per your requirement.